# Fix for CJK punctuation kerning in xetex?

Tags: xetex, punctuation, cjk, kerning, xecjk

When using xelatex with xeCJK to typeset a document in English with Japanese quotations, I get rather unsightly kerning with Japanese punctuation. In general, punctuation is shifted to the left, so that a left bracket `「` is extremely close to the previous character, and a right bracket `」` is extremely far from the next character. Another example is `・` which should be seen in the following example as very clearly not centered.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec,xeCJK}

\setmainfont{Garamond Premier Pro}
\setCJKmainfont[Scale=0.9,ItalicFont=*]{Hiragino Mincho Pro}

\begin{document}

Some text in English and あ・あ and again English;
now we write あ「あ」あ then end.

すべての人間は、生れながらにして自由であり、かつ、尊厳と権利とについて平等である。
人間は、理性と良心とを授けられており、互いに同胞の精神をもって行動しなければならない。

\end{document}
```

Removing `\XeTeXlinebreaklocale "en"` solves the problem (though it would be nice to have the option to have full-width punctuation), but that is apparently needed to force line breaks in Japanese text.

This is a problem that I have encountered for a long time now, but I don't believe I had ever actually found a solution for. Interestingly, using a Japanese font as the main font for the document (without xeCJK) does not result in this, but this is not ideal.

At least on my system (Mac 10.8 with TexLive 2012 64bit), does not appear limited to Adobe fonts. Is this a font-related issue, or something with the system implementation?

[image: image from code above]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I also sugguest our `xeCJK` package for XeTeX, or you can use `luatexja` package for LuaLaTeX, if you need. `luatexja` is developed by a Japanese group. Besides our `xeCJK`, there're also solutions by native Japanese. For example, [`ZXjatype` package](http://zrbabbler.sp.land.to/zxjatype.html) by 八登崇之 (Takayuki YATO), which is based on `xeCJK`. If you're a native Japanese, you may be interested in these solutions.

---

To explain more about the bad kerning without `xeCJK`: This is because the different typesetting rules, the CJK font design and the font support. For western typesetting, there is a space after every word (including the punctuation), but Chinese and Japanese do not use spaces. However, TeX's line breaking and kerning algorithms (`\sfcode` for example) are for western language typesetting, that's the problem.

To solve the problem, one may change the algorithms of TeX in bottom layers, via LuaTeX's callbacks (some Korean projects did this); or one may use macros like `CJK`, `CJKpunct` and `xeCJK` do.

Comment: I did not know about `zxjatype` and I will have to look into it further, but it gives many errors.

I believe you work on `xeCJK`. Do you have any idea why it would produce this strange kerning (http://i.imgur.com/t3t2h.png) on my system and not on another? My install of MacTex 2012 is clean of outside packages.

Comment: I see. Well then the question is how can I get xeCJK to work correctly, as presumably the intended behavior is to correct for this. Since there appears to be some confusion, I have edited the original post to show the code that produces the output in the attached image.

Comment: @afb: I'm sorry but I don't have Hiragino Mincho Pro font. With all Japanese fonts on my computer, there's no kerning problem. I can't reproduce the problem and maybe you need try to change another Japanese font? BTW, make sure you're using latest version of the packages (`xeCJK`, `fontspec`, `l3kernel`, `l3packages`).

Comment: Yes, changing the Japanese font fixed this. I had tried many Roman fonts thinking that might solve it, but not the Japanese fonts, especially since the post by egreg showed correct kerning with Hiragino.

Comment: I find it hard to believe since TexLive 2010 I had seen this problem, but actually, updating with tlmgr solved this! I had just installed TexLive 2012 and the possibility that an update would fix this did not occur to me.

Answer (score 3):

I'd use `xeCJK`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec,xeCJK}

\setmainfont{Linux Libertine O}
\setCJKmainfont[Scale=0.9,ItalicFont=*]{Hiragino Mincho Pro}

\begin{document}

Some text in English and あ・あ and again English;
now we write あ「あ」あ then end.

すべての人間は、生れながらにして自由であり、かつ、尊厳と権利とについて平等である。
人間は、理性と良心とを授けられており、互いに同胞の精神をもって行動しなければならない。

\end{document}
```

[image]

There doesn't seem to be necessary any usage of `\XeTeXlinebreaklocale`.

Comment: Thanks, unfortunately, as I wrote xeCJK has the same problem if \XeTeXlinebreaklocale "en" is used, which is needed (as far as I understand) to line break CJK text.

Comment: @afb To the contrary, the documentation of `xeCJK` seems to say that `\XeTeXlinebreaklocale` is not necessary. I've found a Japanese text in another answer and added it.

Comment: I don't know what to say. With your example changing only the main font, I get the kerning error, yet it appears that now line breaking works. I am not sure what it is exactly that breaks that. Now I am using TexLive 2012, and there is no other version of xeCJK installed. http://i.imgur.com/t3t2h.png (and I can't seem to figure out how to get the image to display inline)

Comment: @afb Sorry, but I don't own Garamond Premiere Pro. Moreover, I get no bad kerning even if using `\XeTeXlinebreaklocale "en"`

Comment: I have tried a variety of other fonts, all to the same effect. I do not have linux fonts, but I get the sense that there is something else at play here ...

Comment: There appears to be a kerning issue with certain Adobe fonts (http://bugs.icu-project.org/trac/ticket/7753) but I also see this in Linotype fonts for instance.

Comment: A follow up: After solving the problem in a test, I tracked down what might have been causing this in a working file set. Adding the font scaling parameter with  `\defaultCJKfontfeatures{Scale=0.9}` instead of an option for `\setCJKmainfont` causes the bad kerning in your test example for me. (I was even able to use the same Roman font with `\usepackage{libertineotf}`).